# I can't get the wireless to work in Ubuntu 12.04 using Sony Vaio VPCEB1E0E

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, vaio, troubleshooting

Hi I am using Sony Vio VPCEB1E0E and i recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 from the ubuntu website using windows installer. Everything else works fine but i cant get the wireless to work. I used the Ethernet to update ubuntu but still the wireless won't turn on. 
I can't even turn it on in settings then network then wireless. My wireless is turned on and works well in windows 7.
Please can someone help me with this problem. I will be the most grateful. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question and add the output of these commands: `lspci -nn; rfkill list all; sudo lshw -C network` (Execute them as one line, the last command will probably take 5-10 seconds to show its definite output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to unblock all wireless devices:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```